# Why isn't it possible to combine LINQ to XML with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I have this piece of code:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var taxReturns = (from t in xml.Descendants("aangiftes").Elements()
    where t.Name == "ib"
    select new Domain.TaxReturn
    {
        FiscalNumber = t.Attribute("sofinr").Value,
        Guid = Guid.Parse(t.Attribute("guid").Value),
        LastFormOpen = t.Attribute("lastformview").Value,
        Name = string.Empty, 
        TaxYear = t.GetAttributeValue<short>("belastingjaar"),
        TaxForm =  unitOfWork.TaxForms.FirstOrDefault(tf => tf.Code == t.Attribute("biljetsoort").Value),
    }).ToArray();
```

When I run this code, I get this exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute Attribute(System.Xml.Linq.XName)-method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

However, when I extract this line into a method, it works fine.

Could someone explain this behavior? I don't understand this behavior :/

Comment: When you get the error, it is trying and failing to translate the expression in the `FirstOrDefault` call into SQL.

Comment: Where does LINQ to SQL come into play here? Did you mean LINQ to Entities?

Comment: @BenRobinson Could you elaborate on that more?

Comment: @Rik unitOfWork is a wrapper arround the DbContext. The unitOfWork goes to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because LINQ tries to compile the code inside `Domain.TaxReturn {...}` into SQL. There is no corresponding API in SQL for `XElement.Attribute(...)` so it fails.

Try to move the `XElement` dependent code outside of `Domain.TaxReturn {...}`
Like this:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var taxReturns = (from t in xml.Descendants("aangiftes").Elements()
    where t.Name == "ib"
    let sofinr = t.Attribute("sofinr").Value
    let guid = Guid.Parse(t.Attribute("guid").Value)
    let lastformview = t.Attribute("lastformview").Value
    let belastingjaar = t.GetAttributeValue<short>("belastingjaar")
    let biljetsoort = t.Attribute("biljetsoort").Value
    select new Domain.TaxReturn
    {
        FiscalNumber = sofinr ,
        Guid = guid,
        LastFormOpen = lastformview,
        Name = string.Empty, 
        TaxYear = belastingjaar,
        TaxForm = unitOfWork.TaxForms.Single(tf => tf.Code == biljetsoort),
    }).ToArray();
```

(untested)

Also, you probably want to use `Enumerable.Single` instead of `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`, or is `null` a valid case?

Comment: Thanks! Does Linq 2 Sql always takes precedence in linq queries? I mean, it is also a Linq to Xml query.. Edit: null is a valid value :)

Comment: The compiler infers from the context if a LINQ expression is to cast to a `Expression<Func<...>>` or just a plain vanilla `Func<...>`. `Expressions<>` are translated at runtime into some other language (SQL in this case) whereas `Funcs` are compiled normally.

Comment: Do you know why the compiler translated this query to SQL? Qhy not to Xml? I mean, I use both now, XML and SQL, yet the compiler 'chooses' to use SQL. I don't get this.

Comment: The compiler sees that `Domain` is a DB context an therefore knows that the code inside the brackets must be translated to SQL via the Expression API. Google for the LINQ expression API to know more.

Comment: Hehe, I posted my comment while you were editing yours :) I did some Googling for LINQ expression API, but cannot find something what I think you refer to. Do your refer to Expression trees?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to know all the details about the Expression Trees (interesting stuff though). You just need to understand, that there is a difference between `Func` and `Expression<Func>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65587/discussion-between-martijn-and-3dgrabber).

Answer (score 2):

As said in the documentation -

> When the application runs, LINQ to SQL translates into SQL the language-integrated queries in the object model and sends them to the database for execution

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Carefully check the execution order, **"The SQL is generated first and then executed"**

You can readily understand why this happens. There is no alternatives of `System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute Attribute(System.Xml.Linq.XName)` in SQL.

For example `.OrderBy()` has an SQL equivalent `order by` and thus when LINQ sees this method it converts it to `order by` and the query is performed. But when linq sees `System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute Attribute(System.Xml.Linq.XName)`, there is no SQL equivalent for this and LINQ throws an error saying it does not recognize it.

But when you extract the line into a method, that method is executed first, so by this time LINQ to SQL has already worked and all the entities you are looking for are brought inside the RAM and now you can perform any LINQ to XML. This time the queries are not converted to SQL, as the entities are already in RAM as managed objects and your code works just fine.

Comment: Thanks. In my examble code I only showed one property that needs an object form the database. In reality I have 6. Should I now create 6 methods to get the objects from the DB? Or is there another, more neat manner?