# How does the compiler determine which provider to use when using multiple Linq2 .... contexts?

Tags: c#, linq

Based on this question: [Why isn't it possible to combine LINQ to XML with LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123507/why-isnt-it-possibile-to-combine-linq-to-xml-with-linq-to-sql/27123799#27123799) I would like to know how the compiler determines which LINQ provider to use.

In question Linq2Xml and Linq2Sql are used and the compiler uses Linq2Sql. I am wondering why this is because both providers are used: xml and sql.

Could someone explain how the compiler knows which one to use?

Comment: you mean which _provider_?

Comment: Yes, maybe that is a better description

Comment: I don't think its anything to do with the compiler its a run time thing. The query will execute using the linq provider of the collection you are querying. In your example it looks like `unitOfWork.TaxForms` is a `DbSet`, so the expression in `Single()` is turned into Sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different overloads of Linq methods. Some of them are operating on `IEnumerable<T>` and some of them are `IQueryable<T>`.`IEnumerable<T>` methods are used in Linq to Objects, Linq to Xml etc.

`IQueryable<T>` on the other hand is created for query providers. From [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The `IQueryable<T>` interface is intended for implementation by query providers.
>
> This interface inherits the `IEnumerable<T>` interface so that if it
>   represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated.
>   Enumeration forces the expression tree associated with an
>   `IQueryable<T>` object to be executed. Queries that do not return
>   enumerable results are executed when the `Execute<TResult>(Expression)`
>   method is called.The definition of "executing an expression tree" is specific to a query provider. For example, it may involve translating the expression tree to a query language appropriate for an underlying data source.

So that's how they are differentiate. But the compiler actually has nothing to do with this, the execution of the query completely depends on which source you run the query.For example in Linq to SQL, assume you have a `dbContext.Users`, it will return an `IQueryable<T>` so the methods you call on this object will use the `IQueryable<T>` overloads and they are convertible to SQL by the `Linq to SQL` query provider. And if you turn them into an `IEnumerable<T>` by calling `AsEnumerable` or other linq methods (`ToList`, `ToArray`), the result will be fetched from DB and the rest of the query will be executed in memory using Linq to Objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand. The explanation about IEnumerable vs IQueryable in LINQ helped me a lot.